# Can I iterate through other resources in main.tf in readResource() when developing a TF provider?

Tags: terraform

Context: I'm developing a TF provider (here's the official [guide](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-complex-read?in=terraform/providers) from HashiCorp).

I run into the following situation:

```
# main.tf
resource "foo" "example" {
   id = "foo-123"
   name = "foo-name"
   lastname = "foo-lastname"
}

resource "bar" "example" {
   id = "bar-123"
   parent_id = foo.example.id
   parent_name = foo.example.name
   parent_lastname = foo.example.lastname
}
```

where I have to declare `parent_name` and `parent_lastname` (effectively duplicate them) explicitly to be able to read these values that are necessary for read / create request for Bar resource.

Is it possible to use a fancy trick with `d *schema.ResourceData` in

```
func resourceBarRead(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) diag.Diagnostics {
```

to avoid duplicated in my TF config, i.e. have just:

```
resource "foo" "example" {
   id = "foo-123"
   name = "foo-name"
   lastname = "foo-lastname"
}

resource "bar" "example" {
   id = "bar-123"
   parent_id = foo.example.id
}
```

infer `foo.example.name` and `foo.example.lastname` just based on `foo.example.id` in `resourceBarRead()` somehow so I won't have to duplicate those fields in both resources?

Obviously, this is minimal example and let's assume I need both `foo.example.name` and `foo.example.lastname` to send a read / create request for Bar resource? In other words, can I iterate through other resource in TF state / main.tf file based on target ID to find its other attributes? It seems to be a useful feauture howerever it's not mentioned in HashiCorp's guide so I guess it's undesirable and I have to duplicate those fields.

Comment: If you were to code that into the provider, you would essentially be locking users into only using exported resource attributes from `foo` as values for `bar`. Without knowing any details about the provider, bindings, or API, I do not know if this would be an issue or not.

Comment: That's a great point @MattSchuchard! Let's say it's not an issue. Surprisingly enough, I looked at other TF providers and couldn't find that others use this approach (of iterating through resources) at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terraform's provider/resource model, each `resource` block is independent of all others unless the user explicitly connects them using references like you showed.

However, in most providers it's sufficient to pass only the `id` (or similar unique identifier) attribute downstream to create a relationship like this, because the other information about that object is already known to the remote system.

Without knowledge about the particular remote system you are interacting with, I would expect that you'd be able to use the value given as `parent_id` either directly in an API call (and thus have the remote system connect it with the existing object), or to make an additional read request to the remote API to look up the object using that ID and obtain the `name` and `lastname` values that were saved earlier.

If those values only exist in the provider's context and not in the remote API then I don't think there will be any alternative but to have the user pass them in again, since that is the only way that local values (as opposed to values persisted in the remote API) can travel between resources.